# hapijs joi email validation option tldWhitelist usage

Tags: node.js, validation, email, hapi.js, joi

I'm trying to use Joi and Hapijs to validate POST submission requests.

Here is my swagger code:

```
  server.route([
    {
      method: "POST",
      path: '/cardsignup',
      config: {
        handler: card_signup,
        description: 'Insert card signup record',
        notes: 'save card signup to database',
        tags: ['card', 'signup', 'api'],
        plugins: {
          'hapi-swagger': {
            responseMessages: [
              {code: 200, message: 'Success'},
              {code: 400, message: 'Bad Request'},
              {code: 401, message: 'Not Authorized'},
              {code: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error'}
            ]
          }
        },
        validate: {
          payload: {
            name: Joi.string()
              .required()
              .description('full name'),
            email: Joi.string().email({
              tldWhitelist:['example.com']
            })
              .required()
              .description('email'),
            signature_svg: Joi.string()
              .optional()
              .description('string encoded svg'),
            signature_png: Joi.binary()
              .optional()
              .description('base64 encoded png'),
            card_choice: Joi.string()
              .required()
              .description('card choice string'),
            last4: Joi.number()
              .required()
              .description('last 4 digits of cc')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

When I do a POST to the server, I get this back, no matter what email I put in:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "child \"email\" fails because [\"email\" must be a valid email]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "payload",
    "keys": [
      "email"
    ]
  }
}
```

Anybody have an example of how to use tldWhitelist?

Specifically, I want to verify that emails are from example.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of [`tldWhitelist`](https://github.com/hapijs/isemail#validateemail-options-callback) can be either an object lookup table or an array of valid top-level domains. For example:

```
tldWhitelist: ['com']
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I verify that emails submitted are from example.com?

Comment: You can use a regex: `Joi.string().email().regex(/example\.com$/)`.